# please help me close this script, it wont work in the broswer after using text editor document

Tags: jquery

I have a simple script that when you scroll the text "WORK AT THIS POINT" to the top of the page, all text on the page moves across. And when you scroll back down, all text moves back across from where it came from. This works perfectly fine in JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/P3XnN/416/

```
$('#waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
//  alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
if(direction==="down") {
    $("p").animate({left:"300px"});
} else {
  $("p").animate({left:"0px"}); // NEWLY ADDED WORKS WITHOUT
}
}, {

offset: '0%'
});
```

However...

When i use the exact same code in my text editor and run it in the browser it wont work

http://itrox.co.uk/waypoint/waypoint.html

Does it need to be closed differently, is there an addition i am missing? Please help

Thanks

Comment: perhaps checking the browser's console would show you: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`

Comment: as @sbksi says you are missing closing tages for your `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @user3681423 you have syntax error and you do not have the waypoints plugin.

Comment: yea thanks a lot, i knew the script was not closed properly because in my text editor i needed to close $(document).ready which is provided behind the scenes in jsfiddle, so initially i closed it up but it still never worked. At some point i got frustrated, removed the closing tags and forgot to put them back, but it was the waypoint plugin that really solved it all. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsfiddle, you're loading the jQuery waypoints plugin as an external resource. But in your own file, you're only loading the main jQuery library. You need to pull in the waypoints plugin as well.

Edit: In addition, it appears your syntax is lacking a closing tag; please see the other comments as well for that.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, you're using a `$(document).ready(function(){` wrapper around your code.

It seems like you're missing an extra `});` to close out the jquery code.

```
<script> 
/// SWITCHES 1 AND 2
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
  //  alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
    if(direction==="down") {
        $("p").animate({left:"300px"});
    } else {
      $("p").animate({left:"0px"}); // NEWLY ADDED WORKS WITHOUT
    }
}, {
   //})
    offset: '0%'

});

MISSING HERE }); 
</script>
```

Proper and consistent indentation can reveal issues like this very quickly. Good luck!